# How to minus by period in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, lead

I need results in minus column like:

For example, we take first result by A = 23(1)

and we 34(2) - 23(1) = 11, then 23(3) - 23(1)...

And so on. For each category.

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
| Period | Category | Result | Minus |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|      1 | A        |     23 | n/a   |
|      1 | B        |     24 | n/a   |
|      1 | C        |     25 | n/a   |
|      2 | A        |     34 | 11    |
|      2 | B        |     23 | -1    |
|      2 | C        |      1 | -24   |
|      3 | A        |     23 | 0     |
|      3 | B        |     90 | 66    |
|      3 | C        |     21 | -4    |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Could you help me?

Could we use partitions or lead here?

Comment: Do what?  You haven't explained what you want to do.

Comment: I fail to see the logic in it.

Comment: what are 'hello' ones then?

Comment: "For example, we take first result by A = 23 and we 34 - 23 = 11 and so on." -- That's not true for 3A vs 2A: the result should be `-11` not `0`.

Comment: The logic, such as it is, is that values that repeat in `Category` subtract from the `Result` column where `Minus` equals 'hello'.

Comment: `NVARCHAR` is not a type in Postgres. You would need to use `VARCHAR`'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *,
    Result - FIRST_VALUE(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Period)   AS Minus
FROM
    yourTable
```

This doesn't create the `hello` values, but returns `0` instead. I'm not sure returning arbitrary string in an integer column makes sense, so I didn't do it.

If you really need to avoid the `0` you could just use a `CASE` statement...

```
CASE WHEN 1 = Period
     THEN NULL
     ELSE Result - FIRST_VALUE(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Period) 
END
```

Or, even more robustly...

```
CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Period)
     THEN NULL
     ELSE Result - FIRST_VALUE(Result) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Period)
END
```

(Apologies for any typos, etc, I'm on my phone.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select b.*, b.result - a.result as "minus"
from t a
join t b on b.category = a.category and a.period = 1
```

Result:

```
 period  category  result  minus 
 ------- --------- ------- ----- 
 1       A         23      0     
 1       B         24      0     
 1       C         25      0     
 2       A         34      11    
 2       B         23      -1    
 2       C         1       -24   
 3       A         23      0     
 3       B         90      66    
 3       C         21      -4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gFnrGiHG7YzieZ5ctpEDya/0).

Comment: could we decide without joins, maybe window functions?

Comment: For window function, see @MatBaille's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just not to duplicate my question

How to do it?

If

For each new Sub period we should repeat first_value logic

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| Sub period |  Period  |  Category  |  Result  |  Minus  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
| SA         |        1 |  A         |       23 | n/a     |
| SA         |        2 |  A         |       34 | 11      |
| SA         |        3 |  A         |       35 | 12      |
| SA         |        4 |  A         |       36 | 13      |
| KS         |        1 |  A         |       23 | n/a     |
| KS         |        2 |  A         |       21 | -2      |
| KS         |        3 |  A         |       23 | 0       |
| KS         |        4 |  A         |       21 | -2      |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: You're just creating partions from two columns instead of one; `PARTITION BY category, sub_period ORDER BY period`